# Finding all triples using Euclids formula

Tags: c++, performance, pythagorean

Our class project was to write the most efficient program we could to find all triples up to a given number where neither (a,b,c) go above that number and than print out the number of comparisons the program made to find the triples. Euclid's formula seems to be the most efficient but does not give ALL  triples. What I have found  is that a factor of "k= 3" will give ALL  triples and not just the primitive.(assignment date is past and I am just trying to find the best algorithm)

My question is , is my counter counting all tests because its telling me I am only testing once per triple.

This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void pythFunc2(int max)
{

    int counter=0;
    for (int n = 1; n <= max; ++n) 
    {
       for (int m = n + 1; m <= max && (m*m + n*n) <= max; ++m) 
       {
            cout<<m<<"+"<<n<<"="<<endl;
            counter++;
            int a = ((m*m)-(n*n));
            int b = (2*m*n);
            int c = ((m*m)+(n*n));
            cout << a << "sqrd + " << b << " sqrd = " << c <<" sqrd." <<endl;
            if(((m*m)-(n*n))*3<=max && (2*m*n)*3 <=max && ((m*m)+(n*n))*3 <= max)
            {
               cout << a*3 << "sqrd + " << b*3 << " sqrd = " << c*3 <<" sqrd." <<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"There were "<<counter<<" comparisons."<<endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: I don't really see a question anywhere...

Comment: Sorry and thank you Brian, I have edited my post  to clarify the question. I am looking for a way to make Euclid's formula work for ALL triples, not just primitives. I have read that a factor of 'k' will give ALL of the triples but have not found a way to implement it.

Comment: Just add another loop for k, I don't see the problem. Have you tried it and haven't succeeded ?

Comment: I have tried to include 'k'( 2 multiplier) in an if statement, but it would double up on some triples.If I add another for loop I am worried about losing efficiency over nested for loops that I can use without Euclids. This is second week of class in Algorithms so I am not very good at calculating efficiency yet.

Comment: To all reading this thread , I think I have found the solution and will post later, the one triple this code didn't find is 9,12,15 which is 3*(3,4,5) so I will now try k=3 in an if statement and post later if it works.